# Laravel 5.2- Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::header()

Tags: php, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I am trying to download file from amazon s3 bucket.

Here is my code:

```
public function GetFile($userID) {
    try {
        $s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
        $file = $s3->get('pathtofile');
        return (new Response($file, 200))
            ->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return '';
    }
}
```

but it is giving error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::header()
```

Please guide me.

Thanx.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modify the class you are using:
Change

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response
```

for

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
```

Comment: But the facade could not be used (considering it is a wrapper of the class)?

Comment: Although the facade helps us use the class easily, it does not implement all the methods from the class. 
As you can see in the [souce](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Response.php) it uses the `Illuminate\Http\Response` class, but does not allow to use the header method.