# Laravel class usage guide?

Tags: php, laravel, class, html5-audio, conventions

I am a PHP beginner and learning Laravel (currently Laravel 9). I have seen some tutorials, and I am experimenting with them. I noticed that there are many classes defined in the framework itself. I want to know whether there is a guide explaining the implementation and usage of these classes.

For example, there are `Illuminate\Http\Response` and `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response` classes. Both seem to have the same usage, but I could be wrong.

There are some other questions, too, like a global namespace `response()` which creates a new response instance, so why would I use `Illuminate\Http\Response` or `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response` to create a new instance?

Are there any guides where it specifies when, where, and why we would use those classes?
Are there any rules for such situations?

I also couldn't find a complete guide for handling audio files and creating an audio player before finding the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53865176/get-mp3-file-from-storage-laravel/63367898#63367898?newreg=f9f14645d8d7488eaeb77510bfdec4bf) in ronline's answer.

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/9.x/ You can search for any class here and see the available properties, methods, etc, including a link to the Source Code where they are defined/implemented. Please note though, this question is off-topic for Stackoverflow. Asking for external resources, like tutorials, documentation, guides, etc. is not allowed here, and your question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find more information about the Laravel classes in the API.
In the case of Illuminate\Http\Response and Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response, you can find them here:

https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Http/Response.html
https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Response.html

If you want more info on the difference between Illuminate\Http\Response and Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response, the facade doesn't have the header method. This is answered here (in the comments):

[Laravel 5.2- Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::header()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457120/laravel-5-2-call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-support-facades-responseheade#37457194)

This website seems to give more information on response objects:

https://laravel-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/responses/